# Is it good way to get variable from ArrayList includes different type of List?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to specify `myObject` map to reach my objects with their ID (given automatically ordered) and I created `List<T>` for each one

Edit: (World, City, ...) those objects has ComponentID variable.

```cs
public enum ComponentType : byte
{
    Effect,
    Building,
    City,
    Region,
    Country,
    World
}

public static class ComponentMap
{
    public static List<World> Worlds = new List<World>();
    public static List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();
    public static List<Region> Regions = new List<Region>();
    public static List<City> Cities = new List<City>();
    public static List<Building> Buildings = new List<Building>();
    public static List<Effect> Effects = new List<Effect>();

    public static ArrayList Map = new ArrayList() {
        Effects,
        Buildings,
        Cities,
        Regions,
        Countries,
        Worlds
    };
}
```

Here I'm checking my object with that method.

```cs
private bool CheckExist()
{
    ComponentType type = ComponentType.Country;
    ushort compId = 12;

    return ((List<object>)(ComponentMap.Map[(byte)type]))[compId] == null ? false : true;
}
```

As you see I'm converting `(ComponentMap.Map[(byte)type]) =>  List(object)` because, I cannot use the `Map`'s variable as a `List`, it's says "it is an object not a list".

Is this method normal or trash? Please specify if you have better solution.

Comment: .IndexOf(compId) returns null if the component deleted by some trigger in app.

Comment: Do you have Id in all your objects? Do you need to save objects, or you need ids only?

Comment: @ingvar I have Id in all objects, for example if I want to reach City which id = 3, i want to use that Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mapping I recommend to use built-in dictionaries and sets, it will be faster and much more readable (I suppose you have `Id` property in your entities):

```
public static class ComponentMap
{
    public static List<World> Worlds = new List<World>();
    public static List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();
    public static List<Region> Regions = new List<Region>();
    public static List<City> Cities = new List<City>();
    public static List<Building> Buildings = new List<Building>();
    public static List<Effect> Effects = new List<Effect>();

    public static IDictionary<ComponentType, ISet<int>> Map = new Dictionary<ComponentType, ISet<int>>() {
        [ComponentType.Effect] = new HashSet<int>(Effects.Select(e => e.Id)),
        // etc
    };
}

private bool CheckExist()
{
    ComponentType type = ComponentType.Country;
    ushort compId = 12;

    return ComponentMap.Map[type].Contains(compId);
}
```

If you want to keep refs to entities you can do following dictionary usign C# 7 tuples feature:

```
public static class ComponentMap
{
    public static List<World> Worlds = new List<World>();
    public static List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();
    public static List<Region> Regions = new List<Region>();
    public static List<City> Cities = new List<City>();
    public static List<Building> Buildings = new List<Building>();
    public static List<Effect> Effects = new List<Effect>();

    public static IDictionary<(ComponentType, int), object> Map;

    static ComponentMap()
    {
         var keyValuePars = Worlds
                            .Select(w => new KeyValuePair<(ComponentType, int), object>((ComponentType.World, w.Id), w)))
                            .Concat(); // add other items in concats
         Map = new Dictionary<(ComponentType, int), object>(keyValuePars);
    }
}

private bool CheckExist()
{
    ComponentType type = ComponentType.Country;
    ushort compId = 12;

    return ComponentMap.Map.ContainsKey((type, compId));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using .NET#4. But if I edit your first solution to `public static IDictionary<ComponentType, IDictionary<int, object>> Map`, is it good or bad? By this way, I have refs also.

Comment: It's also ok, solutions with tuples are just shorter a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists (Worlds, ...) contain object instances. So if you want to use IndexOf, you have passed the object instance you want to get the index of and not an ushort.

I assume that your object instances have an ID property and you want to search your list for that property. If that is the case, you are probably better off using a Dictionary. That way you can access and check for existence in an efficient way. Otherwise, you could use

```
Any(q => q.ID == compID)
```

when you introduce an Interface containing your ID Property.